# Problems with Magento SOAP login

Tags: php, magento, soap

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document

I'm trying to connect to Magento using SOAP and the error occurs when I try to do login. The user exists, password is correct and the user have all privileges. The url that I'm trying to connect is OK and the content too, it's a correct XML. I have used trace = true and all that things.

Here is my code:

```
$mage_url = 'http://mymagentoserver/api/soap?wsdl';
$mage_user = 'soap_user';
$mage_api_key = '********';
$soap = new SoapClient( $mage_url );
$session_id = $soap->login( $mage_user, $mage_api_key );
```

Comment: You should try to call with no cache parameter on , `$client = new SoapClient($url, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));`

Comment: Thank you @AlexandruOlaru but it does not work :(

Comment: Try and include index.php in the url - I've had to use that before: `http://mymagentoserver/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl`

Comment: Thanks @McNab but doesn't work, I still have the same error!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this with SOAP v2

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.comain.co.uk/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('username', 'apikey');
```

Comment: Thanks bro but I'have tested these way too and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

There is an [article describing your error on this blog](https://www.mikemackintosh.com/fixing-soap-exception-no-xml/). They suggest running

```
print_r($client->__getLastResponse());
```

to determine if there is in fact any XML or not. It is possible you have some errant whitespace in your `index.php` or `api.php` file which is breaking the SOAP parser. The article goes further to suggest extending the SoapClient class to override some methods...hopefully you don't have to go that far.

I would also check my `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exeption.log` in your Magento webroot.

Answer (score 0):

You  can try this for SOAP login.

```
//first get user and apikey from admin.

$client = new SoapClient('http://URL/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');    
$session = $client->login('User', 'ApiKey');    
print_r($session);
```